# How do you access the URL in a NextJS app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

In my code I make API calls, but I want to be able to work with both dev and prod, so typically I would do something like:

```
let res = await fetch(`${process.env.SERVER_URL}/api/category/initialCategoryMeta?category=${category}`
```

How can I do something like this in NextJS so I can set SERVER_URL when running the app?

Comment: This lacks a lot of information, please be more clear when you post something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Build time config

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    customKey: 'value',
  },
}
```

This will allow you to use process.env.customKey in your code. For example:

```
function Index() {
    return <h1>The value of customKey is: {process.env.customKey}</h1>
}

export default Index
```

---

> Run time configs

You can setup ***`next.config.js`*** file

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will only be available on the server side
    mySecret: 'secret',
    secondSecret: process.env.SECOND_SECRET, // Pass through env variables
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will be available on both server and client
    staticFolder: '/static',
  },
}
```

And then access the values from ***`next/config`***

```
// pages/index.js
import getConfig from 'next/config'
// Only holds serverRuntimeConfig and publicRuntimeConfig from next.config.js nothing else.
const { serverRuntimeConfig, publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig()
```

[`Next Runtime config`](https://nextjs.org/docs#runtime-configuration)

Comment: Sorry this doesn't address dev vs. prod, this tackles client vs server which is very different.

Comment: @DanFein same way you can setup for build in config file [`build time configuration`](https://nextjs.org/docs#build-time-configuration)